# Automatically add semicolon on return at the end of a block in vim

Tags: javascript, vim

There's similar answers but there for single lines more. I just want to automatically add a semicolon to a block in JavaScript like (the pipe == cursor):

```
func(function(){|})
```

then I press enter and I get

```
func(function(){
|})
```

Could I add a `;` to the end of that line to get:

```
func(function(){
|});
```

automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin for this a couple years ago, [endline.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3163). The default mapping is mostly for GVim, but it is easily overridden to be useful in terminal vim. It structures making some keymapping (`<S-CR>` by default) do add a line ending if one isn't already there, and it moves you to the next line. In normal mode, the character is added, but the cursor does not move. This plugin is particularly helpful for C-style languages and Python, making the tedium of semicolons/colons much easier to handle, especially when you use a script like [autoclose.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) that inserts close quotes, parens, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should give cosco.vim a try: https://github.com/lfilho/cosco.vim

Comment: Except cosco appears poor at guessing whether a comma, or semicolon is in order.

Comment: That's a matter of helping improving its engine. It's an open source plugin afterall... :-)

Comment: Looking back at my previous comment, it feels a bit harsh. That wasn't my intention :). Context sensitive completion for a language like javascript is too much to ask from a vim plugin and very hard to get right without tools like ternjs. I most certainly appreciate the effort you put in this.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure I fully understand your question but ...

```
:1$s/|/^v^m/g
```

The ^ means hold the control key while typing the next letter.  But you cannot append a semi-colon at the same time.

```
:1,$s/)$/);/g
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following mapping to open the `{}` "correctly" (the TextMate way) upon hitting `<C-Return>`:

```
inoremap <C-Return> <CR><CR><C-o>k<Tab>
```

You could modify it to also add a semicolon:

```
inoremap <C-Return> <C-o>m`<C-o>A;<C-o>``<CR><CR><C-o>k<Tab>
```